# eclipse IDE guava-18.0.jar has no source attachment

Tags: eclipse, selenium, guava

I was trying install a newer version of Chrome Selenium driver but the newest version didn't fix a problem I was having. So I copied the previous Chrome Selenium driver back into the same folder where I keep all of the browser drivers.

Now when I try to run my Selenium script in Eclipse IDE I get this error:

"eclipse IDE guava-18.0.jar has no source attachment"

I googled around but cannot find this problem elsewhere to see how to fix it.

Thanks...

Comment: Are you using maven build automation tool? Have you added any break points?